# Remove odd value element from a LinkedList

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was doing an online coding question about removing odd value elements from a linked list.

However, my following code turn out to be terminated due to timeout. I was not sure what went wrong. because the complexity of this algorithm is O(n) and I doubt if there is an algorithm which can do better than O(n). Any ideas?

```
public static LinkedList(LinkedList header){

        if(header.val%2 != 0){
                header = header.next;
        }

        LinkedList current = header.next;
        LinkedList previous = header;

        while(current!=null){
                if(current.val%2 != 0){
                       previous.next = current.next;
                       current = current.next;
                }
        }

        return header;
}
```

Comment: Hint, What happens in your code when the value is even?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Got it! Thanks!

Comment: (Now you've got _that_ figured out: what if the first element is odd? You re-set one `next` for every odd-valued element - is this necessary for runs of _odds_?)

Answer (score 0):

2 cases that will make this code fail:

1. If the input linked list is empty, accessing header.val and header.next may throw exceptions.
2. If there're only even elements, `current` and `previous` will never be advanced, leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: The question assumes the input is not empty. But I got your second point why it will lead to timeout. Thanks!